# A modification of \part style in memoir

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, memoir, parts

I have modified the `\part` command style in a `memoir` document as in the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,twoside,openright,final,english]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makepagestyle{part}
\makeevenfoot{part}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{part}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{part}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{part}{}{}{}

\renewcommand*{\beforepartskip}{\null\vskip 0pt plus -0.3fil}
\renewcommand*{\midpartskip}{\par\vskip 0pt plus 1.0fil}
\renewcommand{\printpartname}{\partnamefont\raggedleft Part} 
\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{Parte\space}
\renewcommand{\printpartnum}{\partnamefont\thepart \\ \vspace{-15pt} \hrulefill} 

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\part{Basics}

\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum

\appendix
\renewcommand*{\beforepartskip}{\null\vspace{.5\textheight}}
\renewcommand*{\midpartskip}{\par\vspace 2\onelineskip}
\renewcommand*{\printpartname}{\reggedleft\partname}
\part*{Appendix}
\chapter{An Appendix}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Why in the blank page relative to the `\part*` command the title "Appendix" is not flushright? In other words, I would like to change the `\part` style after `appendix` in such a way that the title "Appendix" in the blank page is flushright (in the middle of the page). How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is attaching `\raggedleft` to the part title (and name) font, such as by:

```
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\raggedleft}
```

or if you keep it the same, for the other font simpler

```
\let\partnamefont\parttitlefont
```

This works as you can see in these definitions of `memoir.cls`:

```
\newcommand{\printpartname}{\partnamefont \partname}
\newcommand{\printparttitle}[1]{\parttitlefont #1}
```

Regarding your try:

- `\reggedleft` is unknown, I guess it's a mistake and you mean `\raggedleft`.
- `\printpartname` is used for numbered parts, so not for a starred part by `\part*`. You could redefine `\printparttitle` for this.