# modifying part style in memoir class to match ell chapterstyle

Tags: memoir

I've selected ell chapterstyle using the memoir class.  Following tips I found in [Part style in memoir class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49512/part-style-in-memoir-class) and [A modification of \part style in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42489/a-modification-of-part-style-in-memoir) and looking at the ell definition in memoir.cls I've gotten fairly close to matching the part style to this chapterstyle:

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}

\chapterstyle{ell}

\renewcommand{\midpartskip}{\begingroup
 \vspace*{\beforechapskip}%
 \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
 \hrulefill
 \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
 \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}

% numeric instead of roman numeral for the part num:
\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
% ell like Fonts: 
% 
% ragged left: from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42489/a-modification-of-part-style-in-memoir
% (moves the text to the right)
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\partnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily\raggedleft}
% this (without the \beforepartskip of the same form) force the part text higher onto the page.
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vspace*{\fill}}

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{ell}
\part{A lot of Foo}
\chapter{Foo}

Foo stuff.

\chapter{Bar}

Bar stuff.

\end{document}
```

This changes the font to match, and switches from roman numerals, and puts in the ell shaped divider.  However, in an ell chapterstyle the description is inline with the L shaped graphic, and I'm not sure how to manage forcing those to not be disjoint.  Here's what I get for my ell like part style

[image: modified memoir part style attempting to match ell chapterstyle]

compared to the ell chapterstyle format

[image: ell chapterstyle]

The ell chapterstyle in memoir.cls is:

```
\makechapterstyle{ell}{%
  \chapterstyle{default}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily}
  \settowidth{\chapindent}{\chapnumfont 111}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\begingroup
    \vspace*{\beforechapskip}%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
    \hrulefill
    \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
    \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
    \hfill
    \raisebox{10mm}[0pt][0pt]{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
                              \hspace*{1em}
    \end{adjustwidth}\vspace*{-3.0\onelineskip}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \vskip\onelineskip
    \raggedleft {\chaptitlefont ##1}\par\nobreak}}
```

Notice that I've used the body of \chapterheadstart in my modified part.  I'm not sure what part of this style results in the \chapterheadstart being inline with the chapter number.

Comment: Not quite sure what you want? Should it say `Part I` inside the L?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mine is a little more complicated than Harish', and will need a little tweeking from your part

```
\documentclass[openany,oneside]{memoir}

\chapterstyle{ell}

\renewcommand{\beforepartskip}{%
  \null
  \vspace*{\beforechapskip}
  \vspace*{\onelineskip}
  }
\renewcommand{\midpartskip}{\begingroup
  % \vspace*{\beforechapskip}%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}%
  \hrulefill
  \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
  \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}

% numeric instead of roman numeral for the part num:
\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
% ell like Fonts:
%
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\partnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily\raggedleft}
% this (without the \beforepartskip of the same form) force the part text higher onto the page.
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand\printpartnum{}
\renewcommand{\partnamenum}{}
\renewcommand\printpartname{%
  \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
  \hfill
  \raisebox{11mm}[0pt][0pt]{\partnamefont\partname~\thepart}%
  \hspace*{1em}
  \end{adjustwidth}\vspace*{-3.0\onelineskip}}

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{ell}
\part{A lot of Foo}
\chapter{Foo}

Foo stuff.

\chapter{Bar}

Bar stuff.

\end{document}
```

Comment: What tweaking does this require?  It matches the chapterstyle very well (even including the extra spacing of the chapter text).

Comment: Vertical adjustment, it does not match exactly the placement used by the chapterstyle

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the `fill` distances like:

```
\renewcommand{\midpartskip}{\begingroup
 \vspace*{-.4\beforechapskip}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-.5\chapindent}
 \hrulefill
 \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
 \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}
```

The complete code will be

```
\documentclass[openany]{memoir}

\chapterstyle{ell}

\renewcommand{\midpartskip}{\begingroup
 \vspace*{-.4\beforechapskip}
 \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-.5\chapindent}
 \hrulefill
 \smash{\rule{0.4pt}{15mm}}
 \end{adjustwidth}\endgroup}

% numeric instead of roman numeral for the part num:
\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
% ell like Fonts:
%
% ragged left: from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42489/a-modification-of-part-style-in-memoir
% (moves the text to the right)
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\sffamily\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\partnumfont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\sffamily\raggedleft}
% this (without the \beforepartskip of the same form) force the part text higher onto the page.
% \renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vspace*{\fill}}

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{ell}
\part{A lot of Foo}
\chapter{Foo}

Foo stuff.

\chapter{Bar}

Bar stuff.

\end{document}
```

[image]